# MySQL simple function not working on variable declaration

Tags: mysql, function, phpmyadmin

I am trying to define my own `FUNCTION` on MySQL inside phpMyAdmin:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE output VARCHAR
DECLARE temp DATETIME
SET temp = DATEDIFF(NOW(), added)
CASE temp
WHEN 0 SET output = 'today'
WHEN 1 SET output = 'yesterday'
ELSE SET output = CONCAT(temp, ' days ago')
RETURN output
END
```

The error is the following:

> De volgende query is mislukt: "CREATE FUNCTION `DAYSPASSED`(`date` DATETIME) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN DECLARE output VARCHAR DECLARE temp DATETIME SET temp = DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) CASE temp WHEN 0 SET output = 'today' WHEN 1 SET output = 'yesterday' ELSE SET output = CONCAT(temp, ' days ago') RETURN output END"
>
> MySQL retourneerde: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE temp DATETIME SET temp = DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) CASE temp WHEN 0 SET ' at line 3

However I cannot quite see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Which version of Mysql ?

Comment: You need `;` characters between the statements, don't you?

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't seem to change anything and it gives error on `DELIMITER $$` before `BEGIN`. And I thought that phpMyAdmin should handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some semicolons, a length specifier for your varchar, and there are some errors in your case syntax. This would seem to work with a // delimiter;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION DAYSPASSED(added DATETIME) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE output VARCHAR(32);
  DECLARE temp INT;
  SET temp = DATEDIFF(NOW(), added);
  CASE temp WHEN 0 THEN SET output = 'today'; 
            WHEN 1 THEN SET output = 'yesterday';
            ELSE SET output = CONCAT(temp, ' days ago');
  END CASE;
  RETURN output;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d50ba/1).

Answer (score 0):

The answer needs to be the following:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE output VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE temp INT;
SET temp = DATEDIFF(NOW(), date);
CASE temp
WHEN 0 THEN SET output = 'today';
WHEN 1 THEN SET output = 'yesterday';
ELSE SET output = CONCAT(temp, ' days ago');
END CASE;
RETURN output;
END
```

Note the following changes:

- Lines need to be terminated by a semicolon `;`
- `output` needs to have a `DEFAULT ''` value.
- The syntax for a `CASE` is `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... END CASE`

Edit: `temp` should be an `INT`.